# How can I see files changed since a certain date in a certain directory (and its subdirectories) in Perforce?

Tags: perforce

I'd like to see all files that have been changed since a certain date, in a certain directory (recursively) in Perforce?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `files` subcommand:

```
p4 files //depot/foo/bar/...@2015/02/11,@now
```